# Static ip for application deployed on IBM BlueMix for connecting to SMTP Server

Tags: smtp, ibm-cloud, static-ip-address

I have deployed an application on IBM BlueMix. The application needs to use a smtp server for sending emails. The smtp server will only allow requests from a static ip. As the application is on the cloud, it may not always have a static ip. 
In IBM Bluemix there is a service called as Statica, however that is as per the example only for http and https requests. How can we get a static ip for the application to connect to a smtp server?

Answer (score 0):

Your best best for something like this would probably be to use an SMTP server that accepts some kind of login credentials - having the source IP be static is probably not going to be a tenable solution if you're running an app in the CloudFoundry apps on BlueMix.

If you need a static IP, I'd consider running your apps in the container service, or on a virtual.